# Redis Data expiry daily 5 AM - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I would like to expire the Redis Key by specified time every day - lets say 5 AM .

There are few options i can try

1. Insert the Data daily by 5 AM and set the expiry as 24 Hrs

- could not do because the data insert can happen any time during the
  day.

2. Write a Spring Boot Scheduler to delete the key by 5 AM

   - This option we are exploring now .

But would like to see whether any in build mechanism available in Redis to expire the key in a    specified  Time.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Redis has [EXPIREAT command](https://redis.io/commands/EXPIREAT) that does exactly what you are looking for.

Spring Data Redis would expose it as [expireAt](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisKeyCommands.html#expireAt-byte:A-long-)